# Difference in these commands in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

What is the difference between

```
mov eax, [esp+0x20]
mov ecx, [eax+0x14]
```

and

```
mov ecx, [esp+0x34]
```

I think it is the same, is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one does two memory dereferences while the second one only does one, so they can't really do the same thing.  The would do the same thing (modulo modifying `eax`) if you replace `mov` by `lea` in `mov eax, [esp+0x20]` as that gets rid of the first dereference.